# The value of the input is sent even if it does not meet the requirements

Tags: javascript, html

When I click "Add" button, its add the value from "addomain" without meet the requeriments of the pattern.

I want to set pattern to the html with JS and after it comprove if the "value" introduced by user on the input is is complying with the requirements

**Do you know some way to do it all using JavaScript?**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Domain" id="adddomain" name="adddomain" required size="15" pattern="^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]{1,16}[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}$">
<button onclick="addentrys()">Add</button><button onclick="CloseInputA()">Close</button>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like setting the pattern attribute with vanilla js? If so, maybe you are looking for something like this:  `document.getElementById("adddomain").setAttribute("pattern", "YOURPATTERN");` - If you want to check the value using a pattern in JavaScript take a look at `RegEx` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: It can be JQuery if its necessary and not just add the attribute, I need to have something like if ("value"="pattern") {
                             alert "Hello"
}

Comment: @r3dst0rm in this web there aren't nothing about check the value using a pettern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the `pattern` attribute using a `form` (as described by @aMJay), which is the fastest and most elegant solution to your problem.

Nonetheless, if you don't want to use a `form`, you also could check your value only using JavaScript's `RegEx` class.

```js
function addentrys() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("adddomain").value;
  let regexPattern = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]{1,16}[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}$/g;
  
  // To call a specific function
  //console.log(regexPattern.test(inputValue)); // prints true if it matches.
  regexPattern.test(inputValue) ? yourFunctionIfMatch() : console.log(false);
}

function yourFunctionIfMatch() {
  console.log(true); // instead of console.log(true) do whatever you like
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Domain" id="adddomain" name="adddomain" required size="15">
<button onclick="addentrys()">Add</button><button onclick="CloseInputA()">Close</button>
```

**Note:** I don't know if it's intentional, but your expression also matches for a string like: `https`.

Comment: Ok thanks you it worked but can u change console.log if its matches for another function? Only if its match

Comment: You could do something like this: `regexPattern.test(inputValue) ? yourFunctionIfMatch() : console.log(false);`. Whereas `yourFunctionIfMatch()` is some function you can call or define.

Comment: sorry but I'm new at JS and I can't find the way to put yourFunctionIfMatch() : console.log(false); it tells Unexpected token :

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check if your code matches the one above. Seems to me that you are missing a question mark or something like that.